# Fantasy Series Featuring Humans versus Sheep/Ram Bipeds in a World with Cyclic Longterm Climatic Changes

Tags: story-identification

The weather is getting colder and a race of rams is threatening the human population. Both races are at an medieval stage of evolution.
I don't think that magic exist, at some point one of the main characters, a young girl is believed to freeze a river, but it is described as having been undercooled.
There is a religion, possibly focusing on the climatic changes. A large stone wheel is turned by monks pushing the walls in solitary rooms inside the wheel. A male main character takes a tour in the wheel.
I read it in danish in the mid to late eighties, probably published by Gyldendal in a young adult sci-fi/fantasy bookline.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108408/sf-book-where-a-primitive-human-on-another-planet-is-the-protagonist-of-a-tv-sho

Answer (score 5):

Could it be Helliconia Spring by Brian Aldiss? Bulls instead of sheep and I don't remember the wheel, but the rest pretty much fits.

Comment: The monks turning the wheel is definitely from one of the Helliconia books, though I can't remember which one

Comment: It is Helliconia Winter.  From WikiL 

Late autumn. The focus is on the politics of the northern continent Sibornal and on a globe-spanning chase, during which everybody gets Fat Death. The protagonist Luterin Shokerandit is the second son of the Keeper of the Wheel of Kharnabar (in Sibornal, above the Arctic Circle of Helliconia). The Wheel is an extraordinary revolving monastery/prison in a ring-shaped tunnel with a single exit. The Wheel rotates once in 10 years.